# ConnectionString' is not a member of .My.MySettings' in DataSet.Designer.vb After deleting unused connectionstring

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I deleted an unused connectionstring and now I have wasted a lot of hours trying to get it back to work. Cause the rest of the program worked like a char and the connectiontring was never used I was working on another database.

> Error 1   'dbGIPEXConnectionString' is not a member of
>   'GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings'. D:\GIP\GIP+Eindwerk\GIP+Eindwerk\dbGIPEXDataSet.Designer.vb 2544    47  GIP+Eindwerk Error  2   'dbGIPEXConnectionString' is not a member of
>   'GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings'. D:\GIP\GIP+Eindwerk\GIP+Eindwerk\dbGIPEXDataSet.Designer.vb 2957    47  GIP+Eindwerk Error  3   'dbGIPEXConnectionString' is not a member of
>   'GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings'. D:\GIP\GIP+Eindwerk\GIP+Eindwerk\dbGIPEXDataSet.Designer.vb 3583    47  GIP+Eindwerk Error  4   'dbGIPEXConnectionString' is not a member of
>   'GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings'. D:\GIP\GIP+Eindwerk\GIP+Eindwerk\dbGIPEXDataSet.Designer.vb 3901    47  GIP+Eindwerk

All the errors lead to a code that looks like

```
Private Sub InitConnection()
    Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    Me._connection.ConnectionString = Global.GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings.Default.dbGIPEXConnectionString
End Sub
```

I've tried removing

```
<Connection AppSettingsObjectName="MySettings" AppSettingsPropertyName="dbGIPEXConnectionString" ConnectionStringObject="" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="dbGIPEXConnectionString (MySettings)" PropertyReference="ApplicationSettings.GIP_Eindwerk.My.MySettings.GlobalReference.Default.dbGIPEXConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

in the `dbGIPexdataset.xsd`.. Didn't change anything.
Cleaning the project also changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you simply delete your Data Source and create a new one.  You would have to add instance of the DataSet and table adapters back to forms in the designer but any of your own code will just continue to work as long as the names are still the same.